# Under which circumstance is $\left| \sum_{n = 1}^{x}\mu(n)f(n) \right| \ge \left| \sum_{n = 1}^{x}\mu(n)g(n) \right| $

Tags: inequality, summation, absolute-value, mobius-function

I would appreciate assistance in either verifying this conjecture, or perhaps a source relating to similar inequalities involving the Mobius function.

$\left| \sum_{n = 1}^{x}\mu(n)f(n) \right| \ge  \left| \sum_{n = 1}^{x}\mu(n)g(n) \right| \text{ such that } f(n) \ge  g(n) \ge  0$

At the moment, I am stuck in trying to find a proper proof of this conjecture of mine. I have figured out this much so far, using the Triangle Inequality:

$\sum_{n=1}^{x}\left| \mu(n)f(n) \right|=\sum_{n=1}^{x}\ \mu(n)^2f(n) \ge \left| \sum_{n=1}^{x}\mu(n)f(n) \right| \tag{1} $

$\sum_{n=1}^{x}\ \mu(n)^2f(n) \ \ge \sum_{n=1}^{x}\ \mu(n)^2g(n) \ \Rightarrow \sum_{n\in S, 1\le n \le x}^{}\ (f(n) -g(n)) \ge 0 \tag{2}$

Where S is the set of squarefree numbers. While (2) is trivially true, it doesn't help me prove the desired theorem at the moment.

Edit:

I found a counterexample. Note that

$ \left |\sum_{n=1}^{x}\ \frac{\mu(n)\phi(n)}{n}  \right | \ \ge M(x) $

where M(x) is the Mertens function, and yet $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} \le 1$

Comment: What is your conjecture exactly? $f(n)\ge g(n)$ for all $n$ doesn't imply that $\left| \sum_{n = 1}^{x}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f(n/d) \right| \ge  \left| \sum_{n = 1}^{x}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)g(n/d)\right|$ for all $x$, try with $x=6$, $f(6)=f(5)=g(6)=1$ and $f(n)=g(n)=0$ for every other $n$.

Comment: Oh that does look like I meant it as a convolution didn't it? No,$\mu(n)*f(n)$ is just meant to be multiplication. Sorry for the confusion, will fix. Either way, I found a counterexample.

Comment: Yes $*$ usually doesn't mean the standard multiplication, in particular in contexts where we have a convolution (here Dirichlet convolution)